# Группировка данных при выводе на фронт-енд

Tags: python, django

Есть такой код:

```
#show.html
    {% for showtime in showtimes %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="medium-11 medium-centered columns">
                <div class="panel callout radius">
                    Кинотеатр: {{ showtime.showtime_place }}<br>
                    Дата: {{ showtime.showtime_dates }}<br>
                    Время: {{ showtime.showtime_times }}<br>
                    Формат: {{ showtime.showtime_format }}<br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

который выводит информацию в таком виде:
[image: пример выводимой информации]
Как сделать так, чтоб вывод был как [тут](http://vkino.com.ua/show/3667/?city=kiev#!=&cinema=&date=), т.е группировка по Кинотеатру, потом подгруппировка по дате?

```
#models.py
class Showtime(models.Model):
    showtime_dates = models.CharField('Date', max_length=30)
    showtime_times = models.CharField('Time', max_length=30)
    showtime_format = models.CharField('Format', max_length=4, blank=True)
    showtime_place = models.ForeignKey('app_places.place', verbose_name='Place')
    showtime_show = models.ForeignKey(Show, verbose_name='Show name')

#views.py
def show(request, show_id=1):
    return render_to_response('app_shows_and_times/show.html',
                            {'show': Show.objects.get(id=show_id),
                            'showtimes': Showtime.objects.filter(showtime_show_id=show_id)})
```

Формат записей в БД в подобном виде

```
ID…|…………...........Date………………|…….Time | Format | showtime_place_id | showtime_show_id
122,“30 августа, сегодня”,  .|……19:00,…..2D,…………………………………2,…………………………….5
123,“30 августа, сегодня”,  .|……23:20,…..2D,…………………………………2,…………………………….5
124,“31 августа, понедельник”,|.12:20,…..2D,…………………………………2,…………………………….5
125,“31 августа, понедельник”,|.17:00,…..2D,…………………………………2,…………………………….5
```

Пробовал применить regroup, по аналогии с примером из документации

```
   {% regroup showtimes by showtime.showtime_place as cinema_place %}
    <ul>
        {% for showtime.showtime_place in cinema_place %}
            <li>
                {{ showtime.showtime_place.grouper }}
                    <ul>
                        {% for item in showtime.showtime_place.list %}
                            <li>
                                {{ item.showtime.showtime_dates }}: {{ item.showtime.showtime_times }}
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

но расписание в данном случае не отображается.

**UPDATE:**

Сейчас вот так (скажем на примере сеансов Трансформеры 5 в 2х разных кинотеатрах):

```
Кинотеатр Линия Кино
Дата 1.1.15
Время 10:00

Кинотеатр Линия Кино (тот же самый кинотеатр)
Дата 1.1.15 (та же самая дата)
Время 12:30

Кинотеатр Караван
Дата 1.1.15
Время 10:00

Кинотеатр Караван (кинотеатр такой же, как и предыдущий)
Дата 1.1.15 (та же самая дата)
Время 13:00

Кинотеатр Караван (кинотеатр такой же, как и предыдущий)
Дата 5.1.15 (!новая дата)
Время 13:00
```

А нужно сделать так:

```
Кинотеатр Линия Кино
>Дата 1.1.15
-> 10:00
-> 12:30

Кинотеатр Караван
> Дата 1.1.15
-> 10:00
-> 13:00
> Дата 5.1.15
-> 13:00
```

Comment: нужно написать свой таг или в коде питона выдавать словарь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось мне сделать через regroup в шаблоне. Моя первоначальная ошибка была, что я обращался к классу_модели.полю_модели, а нужно было просто к полю_модели.

```
{% regroup showtimes by showtime_place as cinema_places %}
<ul>
    {% for cinema in cinema_places %}
        <li>
            {{ cinema.grouper }}
            <ul>
                {% regroup cinema.list by showtime_dates as cinema_dates %}
                {% for date in cinema_dates %}
                    <li>
                        {{ date.grouper }}
                        <ul>
                            {% for time in date.list %}
                                <li>
                                    {{ time.showtime_times }}
                                </li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Возможно это не самый оптимальный вариант. Если есть оптимальней\правильней\православней варианты, рад буду поучиться.